# Ruby regex validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In a Rails app, I have this current Regex validator below:

```
validates :characters, format: {with: /\A(([a-z0-9])+(-?[a-z0-9]+)*\s?)+\Z/, message: "can't be blank. Characters can only be [a-z 0-9 . # - +]" }
```

My validation for Characters initially only allowed lowercase letters and digits. Now I would like to allow for extra characters **. # - +** how do I structure my Regex now?

Comment: What exactly are you validating? Also, your regex matches an optional `-` as well as an optional space.

Comment: So you mean that `########` is also valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your question if you want to allow a-z , 0-9 and .#-+ only the regex for that would be:

`/[a-z0-9.#+\-]/` and your validation will look something like this:

```
validates :characters, format: {with: /[a-z0-9.#+\-]/, message: "can't be blank. Characters can only be [a-z 0-9 . # - +]" }
```

you can even try that out at http://rubular.com/ . imho thats the best  place to go for ruby regex.

Comment: You can always use \d instead of 0-9.